# Why does this seemingly recursive code work, in skimage's source?

Tags: python, scikit-image

In the module `_denoise.py` of `skimage` I found the following piece of code:

```
def estimate_sigma(image, average_sigmas=False, multichannel=False):
        # some more code here
        sigmas = [estimate_sigma(image[..., c], multichannel=False)...
    return _sigma_est_dwt(detail_coeffs, distribution='Gaussian')
```

Inside `estimate_sigma` there's an `estimate_sigma`? How and why does that work? The imports are

```
import scipy.stats
import numpy as np
from math import ceil
from .. import img_as_float
from ..restoration._denoise_cy import _denoise_bilateral, _denoise_tv_bregman
from .._shared.utils import skimage_deprecation, warn
import pywt
import skimage.color as color
import numbers
```

which doesn't seem to sneak in any new functions.

Comment: What is so mysterious about a function that uses recursion? I don't really get what you are asking for.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the recursive call of [`estimate_sigma`](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/restoration/_denoise.py#L636) is inside an if-clause:

```
if multichannel:
    sigmas = [estimate_sigma(image[..., c], multichannel=False)...
...
return _sigma_est_dwt(detail_coeffs, distribution='Gaussian')
```

Case A) If we call `estimate_sigma` with `multichannel=False`, the function won't get inside the if-clause, thus won't invoke itself and will return reaching the end of its body.

Case B) If we call `estimate_sigma` with `multichannel=True` the condition will succeed, so `estimate_sigma` will call itself. As seen from the piece of source above, when `estimate_sigma` calls itself, it passes `multichannel` as `False`. It means that during the recursive invocation "case A" will happen. This time the program will not enter the above `if` block and recursion will end, ending execution of the function and returning.

---

Basically the idea is: if we've got multiple channels, let's divide them into separate ones and perform sigma estimation on each channel

Comment: Oh, that makes perfect sense now! It seems slightly convoluted when `nchannels = image.shape[-1]` checks for multiple channels anyway, but I guess there must be some special scenarios to justify this.

Comment: The "special scenarios" are grayscale 3D volumetric images. In those cases, `image.shape[-1]` is the size of the last dimension. (When `multichannel=False`; there are also multichannel 3D images!)